# Не могу выполнить dist-upgrade

Tags: linux, debian

Сабж. Почему-то не могу обновиться...

```
dpkg: error processing package nginx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up scarlet-nsd (1.0-vscale-debian+jessie21) ...
insserv: warning: script '3proxy' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service watchdog and 3proxy if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service 3proxy at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service watchdog at depth 1
insserv: Stopping 3proxy depends on watchdog and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package scarlet-nsd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-common
 nginx-full
 nginx
 scarlet-nsd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: не нашёл ни `scarlet-nsd`, ни `3proxy` в [списке пакетов](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages). самосбор или «левый» репозиторий?

Comment: *script '3proxy' missing LSB tags and overrides* — уберите этот скрипт. если он был установлен каким-то пакетом — разумнее удалить (+purge) этот пакет. нужен будет потом — установите оттуда, откуда его брали.

Answer (score 2):

> Setting up scarlet-nsd (1.0-vscale-debian+jessie21

судя по тому, что названия этого проблемного пакета не встречается в официальных репозиториях, это «самосборный» пакет.

а слово `vscale`, встречающееся в его версии, наводит на мысль, что вы пытаетесь обновить виртуальную систему, работающую в «облаке» [vscale](https://vscale.io/ru).

если так и есть, то по поводу возможности обновления виртуальной системы и правильной процедуры её проведения вам следует обращаться в техподдержку хостинга.